# GIT Using Unfuddle Error

Tags: git

Hi I am using GIT @ Unfuddle.com as a repository for my code.
But when I am trying to clone the repository using SourceTree app for Mac, I am getting the following error/warning

warning: apdigital.unfuddle.com certificate with fingerprint 78:be:b6:a5:7a:a2:7f:59:3b:d8:8c:df:87:e6:22:c1:7e:5b:a7:a5 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
user:Authentihttp authorization required
realm: 
2013-02-08 09:31:38.609 Askpass[10452:707] Error (internetKeychainItemForServer:withUsername:path:port:protocol:) - The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
fatal: https://mycompany.unfuddle.com/git/repositoryname
 not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Can anybody help how to sort this out.
I am not able to clone the repository on my machine.

Comment: I always clone using `git clone`, so just try `git clone *remote-url*` and import that into SourceTree.

Comment: Thanks HD1…I tried the way you suggest but still it gives the below error 

fatal: https://mycompany.unfuddle.com/git/repositoryname not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Git Unfundle documentation](https://unfuddle.com/support/docs/git), the remote url seems to be:

```
 git clone https://subdomain.unfuddle.com/git/subdomain_abbreviation/
```

Note the final '`/`', and keep in mind those addresses are case-sensitive, so double check the lowercase - uppercase in your URL.